# GoogleInc.:GoogleAPIs:22 is not a valid Android target platform

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api, cocos2d-x

I am getting this error when compiling my project. I have looked around and most people suggest that the Google API is not installed, but it is all the android api and appropriate google api are installed but I get this error even when I change the target level. I have also manually selected the api in the eclipse project settings and also set the cocos/platform/java/project.properties to 22

I still get this error

Answer (score 0):

In your android sdk directory, execute `tools/android update sdk --no-ui`. The missing android target platform will be installed correctly.